# Enforcing to start a new session in Google Analytics from html email

Tags: javascript, html, email, session, google-analytics

First read this :
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en&ref_topic=2524483

If in Google analytics manual tagging is used and if the UTM source is same so new session is not counted if users has clicked on our email( affiliate link) and visited merchant site second time

How we can start a new session on merchant site forcefully if we have already visited merchant site in less than 30 min of time

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you want to restart a GA session Google provides the [sessionControl](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sessionControl) field:

> Used to control the session duration. A value of 'start' forces a new
>   session to start with this hit and 'end' forces the current session to
>   end with this hit. All other values are ignored.

So that would probably look something like:

```
var sControl = "defaultValueIsIgnored";
if(conditionThatStartsNewSession === true) {
 sControl = "start";
}
ga('send', 'pageview', {'sessionControl': sControl});
```

The "if" clause could e.g. check for your custom UTM parameters.